# Convert Columns to Rows in collection power apps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, powerapps-collection, powerapps-selected-items

How to convert from this collection:

[image]

to like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Only because I had the data already mocked from a previous answer :) )

**UI:** Nested Gallery

[image]

**PowerFX:** Exactly as @carlosfigueira mentioned

Assuming `colData` is the data shown in original post

- Set `galParent` to `GroupBy(colData, "principalDisplayName", "group")`
- Set `galChild` to `ThisItem.group`

**Visual**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible. Tables (like almost everything in Power Apps) are *strongly typed*, meaning that it has a well-defined schema that can be referenced within formulas. Since the values from the collection are not known ahead of time, then you would not be able to reference them in the formulas.

You may be able to use something like the [GroupBy function](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-groupby) to create a collection similar to the one below:

[image: Grouped table]